# iPhone appstore approval  mistakes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, app-store

I am just about to launch my first app to the app-store and I have been reading the 'iPhone Human Interface Guidelines' and associated documents to check what i may have been missing.

I would like to ask what the most common beginner mistakes people do when submitting the app to get it approved.

I am thinking about requirement people are missing etc.

One question is if device rotation is required and if so, is it a requirement to rotate all four directions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Read Apple's t[ips for submitting apps](https://developer.apple.com/news/ios/appstoretips/). And, it should go without saying, make sure you comply with Apple's [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Supporting device rotation is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Not deselecting table view rows after the user taps on them.

Answer (score 0):

rotation support is not required,, I have submitted and app without rotation feature.